# How to fix function calling warnings in c?

Tags: c

```
struct reviewStruct {
  char reviewer[MAX_STR];
  int feedback[NUMBER_MOVIES];
};

int readMovies(FILE *file, char movieNames[NUMBER_MOVIES][MAX_STR])

int readReviews(FILE *file, struct reviewStruct reviews[NUMBER_REVIEWERS])    

int main() {

  FILE *file;
  char movieNames[NUMBER_MOVIES][MAX_STR];
  char reviews [NUMBER_REVIEWERS];

  myFile("cisfile.txt");
  readMovies(file, movieNames);
  readReviews(file, reviews);
}
```

This is my `main` function along with the function definitions, when I compile the program I get the following errors:

> "warning: passing argument 2 of ‘readReviews’ from incompatible pointer type" for the line: "readReviews(file, reviews);"
> "warning: ‘file’ is used uninitialized in this function" for the line: "readMovies(file, movieNames);"

How do I fix these two errors?

Comment: Looks like `char reviews [NUMBER_REVIEWERS];` should be `struct reviewStruct reviews [NUMBER_REVIEWERS];`

Comment: Did you forget to include the body of your functions? `file` and `myFile` are two different variables. You don't do anything with `file` before you pass it to your functions.

Comment: *‘file’ is used uninitialized*. Isn't that second warning self explanatory? If you need further help please provide real complete code. The code above has other syntax errors that you have not asked about so I guess that is not your real complete code. For example, semicolons are missing from the two function prototypes.

Comment: To help us to help you please, (1) Summarize the problem, (2) Describe what you've tried and (3) Show some code. As @kaylum said, there is other things missing.

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and tried to make it run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_STR 10
#define NUMBER_MOVIES 3
#define NUMBER_REVIEWERS 2

struct reviewStruct {
  char reviewer[MAX_STR];
  int feedback[NUMBER_MOVIES];
};

int readMovies(FILE *file, char movieNames[NUMBER_MOVIES][MAX_STR])
{
    printf("hi\n");
}
int readReviews(FILE *file, void *reviews)
{
    printf("bye\n");
}

int main(void)
{

  FILE *myFile;
  char movieNames[NUMBER_MOVIES][MAX_STR];
  char reviews [NUMBER_REVIEWERS];

  myFile = fopen("cisfile.txt","r");
  readMovies(myFile, movieNames);
  readReviews(myFile, reviews);
  fclose(myFile);
  return 0;
}
```

With these assumptions runs without any warnings.
I am using gcc 8.3.0 without any options.

Answer (score 0):

**1. First warning:**
As per what @kaylum said. You are declaring `char reviews[MUMBER_REVIEWERS]`, but when you defined the parameters for your function: `int readReviews(FILE *file, struct reviewStruct reviews[NUMBER_REVIEWERS]`, it is clear that the parameter concerned by the array should be of type `struct reviewStruct`.
So in the line where you got the warning change: `char reviews [NUMBER_REVIEWERS];` to `struct reviewStruct reviews[NUMBER_REVIEWERS];`. That should be a pointer to a structure type, not a pointer to a character type. Or if you want to go more in detail: It is a pointer to an array of structures, the type of the array is determined by the type of elements it holds.

**2. Second warning:**
Now let's take a look at the second warning: `warning: ‘file’ is used uninitialized in this function" for the line: "readMovies(file, movieNames)`
As the warning says. Your pointer `file` was not initialized. Take it as a rule, that you cannot use a pointer without initializing it to something to point to. I believe that you are trying to read from a stream. So just in case you need it, you perhaps may be willing to use the function `fopen()`, which returns a pointer to a stream.